# CRM 2011 + Issue with Two Option Set in javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

Hi i have a created a small javascript functionality where in on load both the radio buttons(Two - Option Set) are set to null and when i click 'Yes' or 'No' a field becomes required.

Here is the Code -

```
document.EntityScript.IsCapableOfAssistInOwnDefense_OnChange = function (context) {
if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_HasSubmitted").getValue()) != null) {
     var field = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_SpecifyDetail");
     field.setRequiredLevel("required");
}
else
    var field = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_SpecifyDetail");
    field.setRequiredLevel("none");
}
```

and on load i have written this -

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_HasSubmitted").setValue(null);
```

Now the problem is

**when i click 'No' for the first time when page loads, the function does not get invoked however when i click 'Yes' the function gets invoked and after that if i click 'No' the function gets invoked**

Not understanding what is the problem.can anybody suggest me what is going wrong.

Comment: When you click No for the first time, the optionset is already set to No? Because in this case the OnChange function is not called

Comment: @GuidoPreite But i have set the two optionset to null on load so nothing is selected onload.

Comment: If you set it to yes, and then to null in the onload, does it cause the reverse problem?

Comment: @user1274646 I've found the onchange events vary depending on what rendering type of yes/no you've chosen. radio buttons worked differently than a dropdown for me. dunno if that's the issue....

Comment: @Daryl hey you are perfectly right i tried setting the value as 'Yes' and then made it null onload..now the reverse is happening.but how do i resolve it???

Answer (score 0):

Put the function in event Onchange on the form property for the specific filed(the optionset). it will invoke the function whenever the value gets changed.

Answer (score 0):

A few things after looking that code.

1. Make sure you are referencing all your JS attribute objects using the logical name of the attribute (ex. 'new_attributename' or 'mobilephone').  In your code you have the following attribute calls which aren't valid.  `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("Specify Detail")`, `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("HasSubmitted")`
2. If you are adding onChange events you should use `attributeObj.addOnChange([function reference])` as outlined in the [SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334409.aspx#BKMK_addOnChange), not  `document.EntityScript.IsCapableOfAssistInOwnDefense_OnChange`

***EDIT***

I was able to get the following to work.  In my form customizations I added the script the account form and added `requireField` as an onload function with the parameters of `"donotemail", "emailaddress1"`.

```
function requireField(fieldName, fieldToRquire){

var field = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldName);
var fieldToRequire = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldToRquire);
if (!field){
    alert(field + " does not exist");
    return false;
}
if (!fieldToRequire){
    alert(fieldToRquire + " does not exist");
    return false;

}

field.setValue(null);

field.addOnChange(function onChange(){
    if (field.getValue() != null) {
        fieldToRequire.setRequiredLevel("required");
    }
    else{
        fieldToRequire.setRequiredLevel("none");
    }
});

}
```

Based on the new code you modified there are still the issues I listed above.  You still aren't adding the onchange event correctly, or referencing the attributes correctly.  The attribute names need to be all lowercase for it to work.

Comment: hey i wrote a dummy code similar to mine that is the reason i wrote it like that...that is not the issue.my code runs but only problem it does not gets invoked when i click 'No' for the first time

Comment: I added a code snippet that works.  The attributes "new_SpecifyDetail" and "new_HasSubmitted" need to be lower case.